# DatePicker in Timer Mode - How to get the value

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker

I'm trying to get a datepicker in countdowntimer mode to simply allow me to select minutes and seconds and then get that value when you click a button.  I set up the picker in IB and use this code, but the result is always Null when I select any combination of minutes and hours and click the button...Obviously I'm missing something.  Any help on getting this to work would be appreciated.

```
@interface ThisPicker : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ThisPicker

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;

    NSLog(@"%@",[datePicker countDownDuration]);

  }

  @end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want in a Hour Minute format

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
  {


    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]]);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that results in 00:00:00, so there must be something else

Comment: You said that you setup picker in IB. So why allocing. remove these line  datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;   in IB set the mode of picker to timer.

Comment: right...that helps solve the problem...thanks (my confusion with IB and programming :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `countDownDuration` is a double.

Try accessing it this way:

```
NSLog(@"%f", datePicker.countDownDuration);
```

**Edit:** What you need to do is link your date picker in IB with the one in code and don't alloc it as it's causing an erase of your data.

**Edit2:** `BuildSucceeded` beat me to it. :)

Comment: That results in 0.00000 when I select 10 minutes..so the problem doesn't seem to be in the formatting of the number...thanks.